# Merging two accounts into a unique one ?

Tags: support, status-completed, openid

because of security restrictions, I logged with another OID account.
With my former account, I tried to add the second OID, but it only allows me to logout... not to add the second OID.

Please, can you merge my two accounts : 3497 and 2385 ?

thx

Comment: of course, I can "show my papers for both identities";)

Comment: Which should be the master? 3497?

Comment: does it matter ? my former account is the 2385 and this account have the max reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've merged 2385 into 3497: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/3497/steve-b

You should be good to go!